# Selenium + Ruby - Selecting Onclick in Outlook

Tags: html, ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select this.

```
<td colspan=2 align="right" class="txtpad">
<input type="submit" class="btn" value="Sign in" onclick="clkLgn()" 
onmouseover="this.className='btnOnMseOvr'" onmouseout="this.className='btn'"        
onmousedown="this.className='btnOnMseDwn'">
<input name="isUtf8" type="hidden" value="1">
</td>
```

When I try this however,

```
element3 = driver.find_element(:value, "Sign in")
element3.click
```

It doesn't work.

How can I click on the button to log in?

Comment: Just making a guess. By any chance, does the second line supposed to be `element3.click()`

Comment: That's not the issue; it works fine for the other lines using element.click.

Comment: As input type is submit so have you tried using
element3 = driver.find_element(:value, "Sign in").submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find_element does not go with :value.

Actually it takes first argument as the way with which you wanna find your element, i.e. 
either by :css or :xpath, after that second string containing data to find particular element.

So in your case, as we know we cant find value with :css, but we can do it with :xpath.

Hence in this case, you can try this

```
element3 = driver.find_element(:xpath, '//*[contains(@value, "Sign in")]').first
element3.click
```

I have tried this at my system. I think this will run perfectly.

Comment: Note: this answer didn't work as written, but I am still very grateful because it led me down the right track to one that did. After checking in Firefox's xpath checker and copying the xpath given there, this was the line that worked: element3 = driver.find_element(:xpath, '//*[@id="tblMid"]/tbody/tr[7]/td/tab    le/tbody/tr[3]/td/input[1]')   After this, element3.click worked.